# How to make quadrants of a city using geohash in Python?

Tags: python, maps, coordinates, geo, geohashing

I want to map a city in quadrants using *Python* and I know that exists a module called '***geohash***' which can return a hash from concrete coordinates. However, I don't know how can I map and split a city in quadrants of **X** size. If someone could enlighten me about how to do it or use another module I'd be very grateful!